# GCM getToken() sends java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT on some devices

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing push notifications, but I receive TIMEOUT exception when calling getToken.

This issue only happen on some devices as SC-03D (4.0).

Here's my IntentService which I use to register token:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCM";
public static final String TOKEN_ID = "registration_id";

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously, ensure that they are processed sequentially.
        synchronized (TAG) {
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls are local.
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String gcm_sender_id = getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(gcm_sender_id, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            String storageToken = PrefsHelper.getTokenId(this);
            Log.d(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try registering the token Using Exponential Back-Off

Following code might help you

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCM";
    public static final String TOKEN_ID = "registration_id";
    private final static int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    private final static int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously, ensure that they are processed sequentially.
            synchronized (TAG) {
                Random random = new Random();
                String token = null;
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
                for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
                    try {
                        token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id);, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                        if(null != token && !token.isEmpty()) {
                             break;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //Log exception
                    }
                    if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                            break;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(backoff);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            break;
                        }
                    // increase backoff exponentially
                    backoff *= 2;
                }
                // further processing for token goes here
            }
    }
```

For more information [see this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ayaanp. I will try with your solution :)

Comment: Hi @Ayaanp, Timeout error still happen with your solution.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't receive the registration token at all ? or do you get one after 1 or two attempts?

Comment: Yes, I don't receive the registration token at all.Timeout error always happen with MAX_ATTEMPTS from 1->5

Comment: can you add your log trace

Comment: Hi, please check file https://www.dropbox.com/s/5liha9dzuvdxyd5/log%20%281%29?dl=0

Comment: have you added a check for google play services before starting this service? see https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7554793

Comment: Hi @Ayaanp, I haven't added a check for google play services before starting this service yet. I think it is root cause.
After I upgrade google play server, this error is pass and I got token id, but I can not receive push.Do you know about this issue ?

Comment: Use *#*#426#*#* to get debug info for Google Play Service. Also make sure you are exchanging the token with your server correctly

Comment: Hi @Ayaanp: Do you have skype ? We can discuss via Skype ?

Comment: Hi @Ayaanp : [here's](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/33ldvuh19yiduw8/AABVZVavjbwl3_03_nHEdTGna?dl=0) debug info for Google Play Services .
Could you please help me check it ?

I tried with demo GCM of google at [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) but I also don't work on this device

Comment: No, you need to take the logs by sending the GCM to your device..
You will get to know if the device is receiving the push and it will print package name of your app when play services forward it to your app

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution is almost correct; the missing part is actually breaking the retry if you indeed got the token:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {

            try{

                _token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);


                if (!(_token == null || _token.isEmpty())) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){

                Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get token; waiting "+String.valueOf(backoff) + "ms");

                if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    break;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(backoff);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    break;
                }

            }

            backoff *= 2;

        }

        if(_token == null){

            //Couldn't get the token!!!
        }
```